# How to remove the gray highlighting when clicking on image input on Firefox for mobile?

Tags: css

I have a form with input type image. When I click on it on Firefox for mobile, there is a gray rectangle highlighting around it.

This is the form code:

```
<form>
    <input type="image" src="image.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="image">
</form>
```

This is how it looks: [Gray highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iy7v8.jpg)

on Chrome for mobile there was a blue highlighting which I removed using:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

But how to do it for Firefox for mobile?

Comment: can you please post the code creating you the issue? I tried to reproduce it but I couldn't do it. If you used the code at the end of [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) as base then you need to remove `background-color: #ddd;`

Comment: added the form code. Just a simple form with input type image

Comment: Show the whole div element that contains the form and css code